# DateTime as a key

Tags: c, datetime, berkeley-db

I'm trying to use datetime type as a key in b-tree BerkeleyDB database. My goals:

1. minimum overhead for datetime storage
2. key comparison by date (to retrieve range)
3. reasonable speed

How to represent datetime in most compact form and use default bsddb's key comparison algorithm?

Is it hard to do this in C and create small Python extension for such tasks? I'm not experienced in C and only able to understand small C snippets (and copy-paste them).

Comment: You can store the Unix epoch, it is as simple as it gets, since it is just a number

Answer (score 2):

What range of datetime values are you interested in?  And what resolution on the time?

As [fge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093528/fge) indicated in a comment, if you want 1 second resolution over a period limited to 1902-2037, then you can use a 32-bit signed integer and the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch, which is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00 (midnight on 1st January 1970 in UTC).  If you want a wider range, then you should probably use a 64-bit signed integer relative to the Unix Epoch.  If you want sub-second accuracy, store a 32-bit signed integer which is the number of nanoseconds.  Note that for a negative time (before 1970), the fractional seconds should be negative too.

One reason for suggesting these representations is that the value can easily be found via standard Unix (POSIX) interfaces, such as `time()` for 1-second resolution and `clock_gettime()` for nanosecond resolution or `gettimeofday()` for microsecond resolution.